# Zend: How do i create custom form elements using setDecorators()?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, decorator

I need the form html like below:

```
<form>
<div class="es_form_txt">Name</div>
<div class="es_form"><input type="text" value="" class="email1"></div>
<div class="clear1"></div>
<div class="es_form_txt">Gender</div>
<div class="es_form">
    <input type="radio" value="" name=""> Male
    <input type="radio" value="" name=""> Female
    <input type="radio" value="" name=""> Other
</div>
<div class="clear1"></div>
<div class="es_form_txt">Country Code</div>
<div class="es_form"><input type="text" value="" class="email1"></div>
<div class="clear1"></div>
<div class="es_form_txt">Phone</div>
<div class="es_form"><input type="text" value="" class="email1"></div>
<div class="clear1"></div> 
<div class="clear1"></div>
<div class="es_form">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="es_form"><input type="button" class="button" value="Update"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

I tried all sorts of solution in here not working! Could anyone point me in right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that when I need to display specific HTML when using [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.introduction.html) the most reliable solution is usually to use the [ViewScript decorator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.viewScript).

Build a normal form using Zend_Form.

```
<?php
//application/forms/Search.php
class Application_Form_Search extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod('POST');
        //assign the view script to the decorator, this can also be done in the controller
        $this->setDecorators(array(
            array('ViewScript', array(
                    'viewScript' => '_searchForm.phtml'
            ))
        ));
        // create new element
        $query = $this->createElement('text', 'query');
        // element options
        $query->setLabel('Search Keywords');
        // add the element to the form
        $this->addElement($query);
        //submit element
        $submit = $this->createElement('submit', 'search');
        $submit->setLabel('Search Site');
        $submit->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'));
        $this->addElement($submit);
    }
}
```

Then build the actual script used to render the form.

```
<!-- ~/views/scripts/_searchForm.phtml -->
<article class="search">
    <!-- set the action and the method -->
    <form action="<?php echo $this->element->getAction()?>" method="<?php echo $this->element->getMethod()?>">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <!-- you can render individual decorators. -->
                <th><?php echo $this->element->query->renderLabel()?></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $this->element->query->renderViewHelper()?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <!-- or you can render a complete element -->
                <td><?php echo $this->element->search?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</article>
```

This currently renders as:

```
<article class="search">
    <form action="/video/index/display" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <dt id="query-label">
                        <label for="query" class="optional">Search Keywords</label>
                    </dt>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="query" id="query" value="" placeholder="Movie Title" size="20">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Search Video Collection!">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</article>
```

Some experimentation will be required to get exactly the output you require.

Comment: This is great but i am wondering if its good practice to have php code in my view files - I really don like it. Anyway your's is one quick solution :)

Comment: there is no way to avoid php in the view files, that's why they are .phtml (php html). You could use a separate template system if you like but it can be a lot of effort for very little reward.